# Instance variables not appearing in Rails ActionMailer and rspec preview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a rails 7 app. Here are the relevant pieces of code:

## /app/mailers/team_mailer.rb

```
def final_survey_nag_email
  @leader_name = params[:leader_name]
  @leader_email = params[:email]
  @team_name = params[:team]
  mail(to: @leader_email, subject: "Your Teams Progress")
end
```

## spec/mailers/previews/team_preview.rb

```
def final_survey_nag_email
        @leader_name = Team.last.leader_name
        @team_name = "Team Candler"
        TeamMailer.with(team_name: @team_name, leader_name: @leader_name, subject: "Your Teams Progress").final_survey_nag_email
    end
```

## /app/views/team_mailer/final_survey_nag_email.html.erb

```
 Hi <%= @leader_name %>! A couple of months ago you created the team <b><%= @team_name %></b> for the Team
```

When viewing a preview of the email above at `rails/mailers/team/final_survey_nag_email` @leader_name is displaying a value, but @team_name is not. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting **team_name** here

```rb
TeamMailer.with(team_name: @team_name, leader_name: @leader_name, subject: "Your Teams Progress")
```

but then you try and access **team**

```rb
 @team_name = params[:team]
```

so you should fix your preview to look for `params[:team_name]`